# Which table of pci codes shall I use?

Tags: 10.04, kernel, hardware, pci

I have downloaded from http://pciids.sourceforge.net/v2.2/pci.ids the last pci.id file and I updated my /usr/share/misc/pci.ids file with it.

**OLD PCI.IDS FILE, March 2010: lspci -nn outputs:**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller [8086:0100] (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sandy Bridge PCI Express Root Port [8086:0101] (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Cougar Point HECI Controller #1 [8086:1c3a] (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB Controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Cougar Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1c2d] (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Cougar Point High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1c20] (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Cougar Point PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:1c10] (rev b5)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Cougar Point PCI Express Root Port 6 [8086:1c1a] (rev b5)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Cougar Point PCI Express Root Port 7 [8086:1c1c] (rev b5)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge [8086:244e] (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB Controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Cougar Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1c26] (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Z68 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller [8086:1c44] (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation Cougar Point 6 port SATA AHCI Controller [8086:1c02] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Cougar Point SMBus Controller [8086:1c22] (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: nVidia Corporation GF116 [GeForce GTX 550 Ti] [10de:1244] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: nVidia Corporation GF116 High Definition Audio Controller [10de:0bee] (rev a1)
03:00.0 USB Controller [0c03]: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1042 SuperSpeed USB Host Controller [1b21:1042]
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8168] (rev 06)
05:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1083/1085 PCIe to PCI Bridge [1b21:1080] (rev 01)
```

**NEW PCI.IDS FILE, Version: 2012.08.15: lspci -nn outputs:**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller [8086:0100] (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port [8086:0101] (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1c3a] (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1c2d] (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1c20] (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:1c10] (rev b5)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 [8086:1c1a] (rev b5)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 7 [8086:1c1c] (rev b5)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge [8086:244e] (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1c26] (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Z68 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller [8086:1c44] (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SATA AHCI Controller [8086:1c02] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:1c22] (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GF116 [GeForce GTX 550 Ti] [10de:1244] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GF116 High Definition Audio Controller [10de:0bee] (rev a1)
03:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1042 SuperSpeed USB Host Controller [1b21:1042]
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8168] (rev 06)
05:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1083/1085 PCIe to PCI Bridge [1b21:1080] (rev 01)
```

**I would like to know if I can normally use the NEW PCI.IDS FILE.**

**EDIT: The same output from a non updated Ubuntu 10.04 system**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0100] (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sandy Bridge PCI Express Root Port [8086:0101] (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Cougar Point HECI Controller #1 [8086:1c3a] (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB Controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Cougar Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1c2d] (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Cougar Point High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1c20] (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Cougar Point PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:1c10] (rev b5)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Cougar Point PCI Express Root Port 6 [8086:1c1a] (rev b5)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Cougar Point PCI Express Root Port 7 [8086:1c1c] (rev b5)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge [8086:244e] (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB Controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Cougar Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1c26] (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:1c44] (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation Cougar Point 6 port SATA AHCI Controller [8086:1c02] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Cougar Point SMBus Controller [8086:1c22] (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: nVidia Corporation Device [10de:1244] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: nVidia Corporation Device [10de:0bee] (rev a1)
03:00.0 USB Controller [0c03]: Device [1b21:1042]
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8168] (rev 06)
05:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Device [1b21:1080] (rev 01)
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no problem in using an updated version of `pci.ids`, it is solely used for displaying a human-readable text instead of a number for `lspci`.

As described in the manual page of lspci:

> /usr/share/misc/pci.ids
>   A  list  of  all  known  PCI ID's (vendors, devices, classes and subclasses). Maintained at http://pciids.sourceforge.net/, use the update-pciids utility to download the most recent version.

Comment: I cannot find /usr/share/hwdata within Ubuntu 10.04. I have compared the files at /usr/share/misc/ between to different systems that I use on the same computer, both are Ubuntu 10.04, but one of these was not updated, they are identical. However both system output different names from the same (lspci -nn) command. At the updated system I tried lspci -nnvvq, I suppose that lspci has some file cache where it updates the PCI ID database for unknown ID's via DNS. Is it so?

Comment: Please use `sudo update-pciids` instead of manually downloading, moving, etc.

Comment: @Salvador I updated the path. On Arch Linux it gets installed on a different place, but that does not change the intent of the answer. If you look at the manual page of lspci, you will see that IDs that have been looked up are cached in `~/.pciids-cache`.

Comment: @Lekensteyn I cannot find **~/.pciids-cache** with the tool that I normally use: **locate pciids**

Comment: `locate` works with a database that is regularly updated using a cronjob that runs `updatedb`. Just open your file browser and show hidden files. Alternatively: `ls -l ~/.pciids-cache`

Comment: @Lekensteyn. I got it with sudo find / -iname "*pciids*". It was at the root folder. Thanks.